# Gauss quadrature on weighted function

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I am given a function 
$\int_0^1$w(x)f(x)dx, w(x) = -ln(x). I am asked to find the abscissas and weights for the 1 and 2 point Gauss quadrature.

I know to do this, you start with 
$$\int_0^1w(x)f(x)dx = w_1(x)f(x_0)$$
and let f(x) = 1 to find $w_1(x)$ and then let f(x) = x to get $x_0$. 
This I understand. However, I am ever so confused on how to deal with -ln(x).

When you begin, we have that $$\int_0^1-ln(x)dx$$ and $$\int_0^1-xln(x)dx$$ are undefined because $ln(0)$ and $ln(0^0)$ are undefined. How can you possibly find the weights and points?
Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to deal with this?

Comment: Can you post the exact question? It is not making much sense...

Comment: @PierreCarre This is the exact problem. Find the Gaussian quadrature weights and abscissas (the x-values) for the above integral, where w(x) = -ln(x). It doesn't make much sense to me either, which is why I am wondering if it is my professor's mistake or my own.

Comment: $\int_0^1 w(x) f(x) dx$ is a number... So $w_1(x) f(x_0)$ is just a constant, and $w_1(x)$ is just a number. Also, as you point out, the integral is divergent when $f(x)=1$, so you should start with $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited]

I believe that the objective is to find a quadrature of the form 
$$
\int_0^1 -\log x \cdot f(x) \,dx \approx A_0 f(x_0)
$$

You can determine $A_0, x_0$ by requiring the formula to be exact for $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=x$. This leads to
$$
A_0 = 1, \quad A_0 x_0 = \frac 14
$$

that is, $x_0= \frac 14$ and $A_0= 1$.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still a little unclear about why f(x) = x or f(x) = x^2 is defined. It seems that the problem lies in the fact that ln(0) is undefined, or in the case of -ln(0), infinity. Where f(x)=1, you say the integral diverges, we assume here that 0ln(0) is undefined. But, in f(x) = x, you assume the integral converges by assuming 0ln(0) = 0. Why is this?

Comment: @user728757 Have you studied improper integrals? For instance, you define  $$\int_0^1 x \log x\, dx = \lim_{a\to 0} \int_a^1 x \log x \, dx.$$ In fact, you can just notice that $\lim_{x \to 0} x \log x  =0$.

Comment: @user728757 When $f(x) = 1$ you never get $0 \log 0$. You simply get $\log 0$, which is not an indetermination, it is $-\infty$ and the integral actually diverges.

Comment: Ah, that's right. An application of L'hopitals. That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: $$\int-\ln x\,dx=-x\ln x+x+C$$
And
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}-x\ln x=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{-\ln x}{\left(\frac1x\right)}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\left(-\frac1x\right)}{\left(-\frac1{x^2}\right)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}x=0$$
So
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1-\ln x\,dx&=\lim_{a\rightarrow0^+}\int_a^1-x\ln x\,dx=\lim_{a\rightarrow0^+}\left[-x\ln x+x\right]_a^1\\
&=\lim_{a\rightarrow0^+}\left[1+a\ln a-a\right]=1\end{align}$$
Converges.

Comment: OK, so now show that $$P_2(x)=x^2-\frac57x+\frac{17}{252}$$ and so get the $2$-point formula...